# jQuery index of child in parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a trouble with jquery index function.

I have div with another divs in it, and I want to figure out if its first, second or third div inside that parent div.

So ia have something like this:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Now, when I click on the last child for example, the event.target will be last div with class row.

Now I do:

```
$(event.target).parent().index($(event.target));
```

But this fails as its returning me value -1 insted of 2 ( if indexed from zero ).

Do you have any idea? Thank you.

EDIT:

So, I'm simplified the structure first and thought I just need to understand the concept, but looks like you need to know whole structure so here it is:

```
<div class="ten wide column schichtplan-body">
<div class="row">
    <div class="eight wide column"></div>
    <div class="eight wide column schicht-buttons">
        <!-- Radio buttons for schicht selection -->
        <div class="ui form">
            <div class="inline fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                        <input type="radio" name="schichtMode" value="8hx3">
                        <label>8 Stunde schicht</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                        <input type="radio" name="schichtMode" value="12hx2">
                        <label>12 Stude schicht</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of radio form -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui grid row">
    <div class="four wide column">
        <div class="date-field active">   {{day.date.sec|date('d.m.Y')}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="twelve wide column">
        <div class="button-row">
            <div class="">F</div>
            <div class="">N</div>
            <div class="">frei</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I click on one of the buttons, but I want to find out the index of the .ui.grid.row in which the buttons are. So I need to go throught few parent element and then find which .ui.grid.row is actually selected relatively to .ten.wide.column

Comment: You probably need `$(this).index()` or `$(event.target).index()`?

Comment: Are `.row` elements added dynamically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following `jQuery` :

```
$(".column div").click(function () {
    alert( $(this).index() );
});
```

**NOTE :** *This will return a zero-based index*

See this below :

```js
$(".column div").click(function () {
    alert( $(this).index() );
});
```

```css
.row {
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** : *Based on my understanding of the edited part of the question, here's the answer. The second alert will give you the index of the `ui grid row` (which will contain the clicked element) with respect to the main `ten wide column`. I have added coloring to make it clear. Please see this below :*

**I am not sure if javascript's alerts do display here. In case it doesn't, check out this fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/ynu0x0jw/

```js
$(".button-row > div").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('red');
    var currentElementIndex = $(this).index();
    var parentIndex = $(this).closest(".ui.grid.row").index();
    
    alert("Index of the selected element with respect to its parent (div with class of ui.grid.row) is " + currentElementIndex);
    $(this).removeClass('red');    
    $(this).closest(".ui.grid.row").addClass('red');
    
    alert("Index of the selected element's parent (ui.grid.row) with respect to the main container (ui.grid.row) is " + parentIndex);
 $(this).closest(".ui.grid.row").removeClass('red');
});
```

```css
.button-row > div {
    background-color: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.ui.grid.row {
    background-color: white;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.button-row > div.red, .ui.grid.row.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ten wide column schichtplan-body">
    <div class="ui grid row">
        <div class="four wide column">
            <div class="date-field active">First ui.grid.row (Index : 0)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="twelve wide column">
            <div class="button-row">
                <div class="">A (Index : 0)</div>
                <div class="">B (Index : 1)</div>
                <div class="">C (Index : 2)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui grid row">
        <div class="four wide column">
            <div class="date-field active">Second ui.grid.row (Index : 1)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="twelve wide column">
            <div class="button-row">
                <div class="">D (Index : 0)</div>
                <div class="">E (Index : 1)</div>
                <div class="">F (Index : 2)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui grid row">
        <div class="four wide column">
            <div class="date-field active">Third ui.grid.row (Index : 2)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="twelve wide column">
            <div class="button-row">
                <div class="">G (Index : 0)</div>
                <div class="">H (Index : 1)</div>
                <div class="">I (Index : 2)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui grid row" id="III">
        <div class="four wide column">
            <div class="date-field active">Fourth ui.grid.row (Index : 3)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="twelve wide column">
            <div class="button-row">
                <div class="">J (Index : 0)</div>
                <div class="">K (Index : 1)</div>
                <div class="">L (Index : 2)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm not sure if it will work in my case actually. I'm simplified the real structure of HTML actually. I will edit my question

Comment: @MichalTakáč If I understand correctly, you have a single `ten wide column` div having multiple `ui grid row` divs. These `ui grid row` in turn having these clickable buttons. So when a button is clicked, you want the relative index of the `ui grid row` with respect to the main container `ten wide column`. Is that correct?

Comment: @MichalTakáč I have edited my answer. Please see it. It answers the edited question. Sorry for the delay. :)

Comment: You're my hero Satwik :) Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this).index()` or `$(event.target).index()` asssuming you want the index of the specific row. Below example is with the `.click`, but it will work as long as `this` or `event.target` is one of the row div.

```js
$('div.row').on('click', function(event) {
  $('#result').html($(event.target).index()); //or use $(this).index()
});
```

```css
.row {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
}
#result {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
<div>Index is: <span id="result"></span> 
</div>
```